# How to use CoreMotion in WatchKit?

Tags: ios, watchkit, core-motion

I was quite dubious on this question's title phrasing, but I think that's the whole point as it is.

I've been trying to just read the CoreMotion data on the WatchKit, but as it turns out, I can't get `startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue` to work, my handler is never called.

I tried running in a custom background thread (`NSOperationQueue()`), still no luck.

I'm debugging on a real Apple Watch, not the simulator.

In my `WKInterfaceController`:

```
let manager = CMMotionManager()

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
    let communicator = SessionDelegate()
    manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1 / 60
    manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (motionerOp: CMDeviceMotion?, errorOp: NSError?) -> Void in
        print("got into handler")
        guard let motion = motionerOp else {
            if let error = errorOp {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        print("passed guard")
        let roll = motion.attitude.roll
        let pitch = motion.attitude.pitch
        let yaw = motion.attitude.yaw
        let attitudeToSend = ["roll": roll, "pitch": pitch, "yaw": yaw]
        communicator.send(attitudeToSend)
    }

    print("normal stack")
}
```

the output is

```
normal stack
normal stack
```

(Yes, twice! I don't know why that either, but that is not the point, must be another thing I'm doing wrongly)

I'm posting this here 'cause I have no clue to where look into, this is freaking crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device Motion (`startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue`) is not available in WatchOS2 yet (`deviceMotionAvailable` returns false), probably accelerometer can help you `startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! So, there's no way to read gyroscopic data in WatchOS2?

Comment: Gyro is also not yet available, just accelerometer

Comment: Even with self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue its not working. However isAccelerometerAvailable returns YES.